# Couchdb how to map reduce

Tags: node.js, mapreduce, couchdb, bigdata, nosql

This is my sample JSON structure stored in couchdb:

```
[{"_id":"567567983d6229ccf572c1a2fcad2fbd6","_rev":"1-8666754b35b18c92f005bb64d9c04712a5f","startTime":1467985647,"uuid":"216743afa424dfsf","from":"IN","to":"NG","duration":"121"},{"_id":"4774f983d6229ccf572c1a2fcad2fbd6","_rev":"1-8e9fb35b18c92f005bb64d9c04712a5f","startTime":1467983347,"uuid":"2134jl13k4j343l243","from":"US","to":"DE","duration":"210"}]
```

Using reduce function can we produce an output like:

```
{
   outgoing : {US:1, IN:1}, inbound: {NG:1, DE:1}, duration:331
}
```

Comment: You can probably do this in a reduce function but I don't think this is the right way to do it. **Reduce** functions are supposed to reduce the information, not create structured data. You might want to handle the data on the client site and us specific keys on your map function.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use a reduce function for this. The [view documentation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/couchapp/views/intro.html#lessons-learned) says:

> If you don’t reduce your values to a single scalar value or a small fixed-sized object or array with a fixed number of scalar values of small sizes, you are probably doing it wrong.

Instead, you could use a **list function**, which allows you to transform the rows of a given view result in any way you like.
I found this guide helpful: [Rendering Content Based-On Multiple Documents with List Functions](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/transforming.html)

Comment: we are already using list but there are millions of documents which makes the whole process slower.